# .next() method and skipping specific elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the jQuery `.next()` method to iterate list items. I need to use the `.next()` method to cycle through elements. `.filter-selected` is a dynamically added class on click that changes the style but also serves as a marker for the next element to be triggered.

Take this example:

```
<ul>
<li class="filter-selected title-available"><a href="#" class="filter-item">v</a></li>
    <li class="title-available"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
    <li class="title-unavailable"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
    <li class="title-available"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
    <li class="title-unavailable"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have a button that the triggers this line:

```
$(".filter-selected").next("li.title-available").children().trigger('click');
```

The expected behavior is that it triggers only the `li` items that have the class `.title-available` but what happenes is when the class `.filter-selected` is above an `li` with `.title-unavailable` it triggers it anyways on `.title-unavailable`, even though I pass the specific classname into the `.next()` event that I want it to go next to li items with that classname only.

Why is that? Howcome passing a class into `.next()` doesn't control specific elements with specific classnames? Based on what I can see in the documentation [you can do this.](https://api.jquery.com/next/) Howcome it doesn't work in my instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery's [`next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/) retrieves only "the *immediately following* sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling *only if it matches that selector*."

When the immediately following sibling does not match the selector, nothing is retrieved.

You might have more success using [`nextAll()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextAll/) and [`first()`](https://api.jquery.com/first/) to select all matching subsequent siblings and then choose the first one.

```js
$(".filter-selected").nextAll(".title-available").first().children().toggleClass('selected');
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="filter-selected title-available"><a href="#" class="filter-item">v</a></li>
  <li class="title-unavailable"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
  <li class="title-unavailable"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
  <li class="title-available"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
  <li class="title-unavailable"><a href="#" class="filter-item">item</a></li>
</ul>
```